# Bitlocker on Windows 10

Tags: encryption, decryption, bitlocker, data-recovery

A year and a half ago I successfully encrypted my external Western Digital hard drive using Bitlocker. After a few days I disabled Bitlocker, so the decryption process started. Halfway through this process my computer got shut down due to power issues, so the decryption process got corrupted. Whenever I used that external hard drive again it would try to decrypt, but never really resumed the process, and after a few seconds would show an error, but it never asked me for a password in my computer or any other random ones.

Now it has started asking for a password or recovery key. The problem is, I don't have the password anymore, and I have formatted my PC multiple times so the recovery key is lost.

Is there anything that I can do to get my data back?

Answer (score -1):

If you can't decrypt the drive with your password, or with the recovery options, you still can try the recovery tool. Search for the official Microsoft tool Repair-bde.exe (BitLocker Repair Tool) for the newest version. Use this only as the last recourse.

Note: the best way of dealing with such problems is preventively (i.e. doing a back-up).

Comment: In order to use BitLocker Repair Tool to recover a drive, you must have at least one of the following for the BitLocker encrypted drive: 1. Password 2.   Recovery key 3. Startup key .BEK file location Marz's PC has been formatted multiple times, and Marz doesn't have the BitLocker password or the recovery key either.